# Java: Game of Craps: Exiting a loop then re-entering

Tags: java

This is a program that similates the dice game Craps. The rules are if you roll a 7 or 11, you win. If you roll a 2, 3, or 12, you lose. If you roll anything else you get a "point" and are allowed to roll again. If you allot 2 points you win as well.

The trouble I'm having here is with the point system. I dont know how to store the point, then exit the loop and prompt the user to roll again to re enter the loop.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DiceGame {

    public static void main(String args[ ]) {

        // declarations

        int dieNumber1,
                dieNumber2,
                point,
                score;

        // initializations

        dieNumber1 = (int)(Math.random( ) * 6 + 1);
        dieNumber2 = (int)(Math.random( ) * 6 + 1);
        score = dieNumber1 + dieNumber2;  

        // executable statements

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {

            System.out.println ("Roll the die");
            System.out.println ("You rolled a " + score);

            if (score == 11 || score == 7)
            {
                System.out.println ("You Win!");
                break;
            }

            if (score == 2 || score == 3 || score == 12)
            {
                System.out.println ("You Lose.");
                break;   
            }

            if (score == 4 || score == 5 || score == 6 || score == 8 || score == 9 || score == 10)
            {
                point = 1;
                System.out.println ("You got a point.");
            }


        }


        System.exit(0);

    } // end of the main method

} // end of the class
```

Comment: I think there are two loops here, but this isn't it: `I dont know how to store the point, then exit the loop`  If you want to roll dice and store a point, that's not a loop.  Try writing just that code in a method, then look at it and find the loop (which will be somewhere else).  Basically what we're doing her is breaking down the problem into smaller chunks until it makes sense.  "Roll two dice and record the result" is a suitably small chunk that it can be dealt with independently.

Comment: You're rules are about 0% correct.  First; Craps is a state machine.  For bets on the pass line, when the game is Off, a 7 or 11 wins and a 2, 3, or 12 loses.  Other numbers establish a point and the game transitions to the On state.  When the game is on, a pass line bet wins if you roll the point, the pass line bet loses if you roll a 7, and there is no decision if any other number is rolled.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to think explicitly about how your program's flow should run. Namely: each roll has three outcomes: win, loss, and point. When do we want to loop? I assume (your answer may be different) *when we want to roll again*. When do we want to roll again? I assume (your answer might be different) *when the user gets a point*. Therefore, the point case should be the outcome in which we loop, and any other outcome should result in **not** looping.

Note that because we always need to roll before proceeding with any other logic (can't decide on a win/loss/point if we don't roll), we put the rolling logic inside the loop:

So what will our code look like?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DiceGame {

    public static void main(String args[ ]) {

        // Initialize some things (omitted)

        while(true) { // NOTE: it's generally good form to use while(true) for a loop that could continue forever, instead of a for-loop with a very high number
            // Roll the dice (omitted)
            if (score == 11 || score == 7)
            {
                System.out.println ("You Win!");
                break; // Game over. Get out of our infinite loop.
            }
            if (score == 2 || score == 3 || score == 12)
            {
                System.out.println ("You Lose.");
                break; // As above
            }
            else // If our score is anything else we must have gotten a point
            {
            point = 1; // Don't break. We want to roll again
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your initialization inside the loop, wait for some user input to roll again and increase the points if they get a point.

This should give you what you need

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiceGame {

    public static void main(String args[ ]) {

        // declarations
        int dieNumber1 = 0,
            dieNumber2 = 0,
            point = 0,
            score = 0;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);        

        // executable statements
        // Repeat until score is 2 (or break is called)
        while( point < 2 ){

            // initializations
            dieNumber1 = (int)(Math.random( ) * 6 + 1);
            dieNumber2 = (int)(Math.random( ) * 6 + 1);
            score = dieNumber1 + dieNumber2;  


            System.out.println ("Roll the die");
            System.out.println ("You rolled a " + score);

            if( score == 11 || score == 7 ){
                System.out.println ("You Win!");
                break;
            }

            if( score == 2 || score == 3 || score == 12 ){
                System.out.println ("You Lose.");
                break;   
            }

            if( score == 4 || score == 5 || score == 6 || score == 8 || score == 9 || score == 10 ){
                point = point + 1; // You could use point++ or point += 1 as well

                System.out.println ("You got a point. Total number of points: " + point);

                if( point == 2 ){
                    System.out.println("You Win!");
                }
                else{                
                    // Wait until user presses Enter, then roll again
                    System.out.println ("Press Enter to roll again.");
                    scanner.nextLine();
                    scanner.reset();
                }
            }


        }


        System.exit(0);

    } // end of the main method

} // end of the class
```